# Exit command in GitHub Actions workflow on windows-latest

Tags: command-line, github-actions, windows-server

I'm attempting to translate a simple GitHub Actions workflow from running on `ubuntu-latest` to `windows-latest`.

```yaml
---
name: Run extract_members.py on a schedule

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 6 * * *'

jobs:
  extract:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.12'
      - name: Install requirements
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Run script
        run: python github_actions_test.py
      - name: Commit and push if the data has changed
        run: |-
          git config user.name "Automated"
          git config user.email "actions@users.noreply.github.com"
          git add -A
          git commit -m "Updated data" || exit 0
          git push
...
```

But where there are no changes to commit the workflow errors, with the following information: `The term 'exit' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

I thought `exit` was a [legitimate command on Windows Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/exit), as it is on Ubuntu. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run on windows uses powershell core (`pwsh`), not the windows commandline by default.

So the line should probably read something along these lines:

```
& git commit test
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { exit 0; }
```

where `exit 0;` could also be `return;` to just skip the rest of the script.

If you want to run it as a windows shell script, add:

```yaml
- name: Commit and push if the data has changed
  run: |-
     git config user.name "Automated"
     git config user.email "actions@users.noreply.github.com"
     git add -A
     git commit -m "Updated data" || exit 0
     git push
  shell: cmd                     # <-- Specify the Windows Commandline explicitly
```

If you want all your `run:` blocks to use `cmd` as default shell, you can set the defaults:

```yaml
defaults:
  run:
    shell: cmd
```